# 4 using statements looks messy? Any suggestions on what is a better way to code this?

Tags: object-model, best-practices, dispose

Imagine the following code:

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(this.SiteURL))
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
         using (SPSite spSite2 = new SPSite(this.SiteURL2))
        {
            using (SPWeb spWeb2 = spSite2.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Run a long loop here
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

It looks really messy to me, but During the "long loop" I reference both sites, and I can't take the performance knock of recreating the `SPSite2` and `SPWeb2` objects with each iteration in the loop.

If you came across this code in a code review session, do you think it would be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple assignments in one [`using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(this.SiteURL), spSite2 = new SPSite(this.SiteURL2))
using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb(), spWeb2 = spSite2.OpenWeb()) 
{
  //Run a long loop here
}
```

<sup>Compiled by hand</sup>

(I don't know if you can put `new SPSite()` and `spSIte.OpenWeb()` in one `using`, that will further 'clean-up' the code) --> [Turns out you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966086/using-various-types-in-a-using-statement-c).

**Update**:
You can [only have one type in a `using`-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966086/using-various-types-in-a-using-statement-c), similar to defining multiple variables of the same type on one line.

And you can optimze further by not adding curly-brackets to the first `using`-statement.

Comment: Tried it doesn't compile.

Comment: I said: compiled by hand, now you know why :) I'll update.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment?

Comment: +1 This is what I'd do, minus the "optimization" of missing out the outer curlies.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 4 usings (!) in this case I would rather use:

```
try
{
     SPSite spSite = new SPSite(this.SiteURL);
     SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();
     SPSite spSite2 = new SPSite(this.SiteURL2);
     SPWeb spWeb2 = spSite2.OpenWeb()

     // some code
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
     //Handle exception
}
finally 
{
     if(spWeb2 != null) spWeb2.Dispose();
     if(spSite2 != null) spSite2.Dispose();
     if(spWeb != null) spWeb.Dispose();
     if(spSite != null) spSite.Dispose();
}
```

It's not perfect but 4 usings + eg. 1 foreach + 1 if .... and you need second monitor just to read code.

If you are reading webs from same site collection then maybe better solution is this:

```
 //Site url is site collection url
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.SiteURL))
 {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/url1"))
      {
           using (SPWeb web2 = site.OpenWeb("/url2"))
           {
                //some code
           }
      }
 }
```

**Edited:**

After reading @Wictor-SharePointMVP comment I updated code with try catch finally block. Be sure that you always follow [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx#sharepointobjmodel__codingtechniques)

Comment: This might be dangerous, what if your code throws an exception!?

Comment: @Wictor-SharePointMVP I don't do exceptions :) Thx for the comment. I really need to be more careful when posting answers. I am always lecturing my colleagues about object disposal and then I make this obvious error (i am a bit ashamed right now)

Comment: If an exception happens before you initialize one of the SPSite/SPWeb objects, calling .Dispose() on it will also error!

Comment: This SPSE editor is playing with my head. This was not the last version I saved. Thx. Code is now edited (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problems with code like this:

- The developer understands that he/she must dispose correctly according to the "best practices"
- It's easy to follow

It's good that the objects are not recreated in the inner "long loop" and this case takes care of when you're having different site collections.

Combining the using statements as Dribbel suggests would likely call to my attention and I would expand them. You'll likely make more mistakes using a composite using statement. And it does not impact performance a bit, you'll save a line or two of codes and risk missing out on a dispose.

Comment: I agree. The code is self explanatory on what you are doing and I don't see this as a problem.